# IOS, convert from Obj-c to swift

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone help me convert this method into swift?

```
-(void) camera:(DJICamera*)camera didReceivedVideoData:(uint8_t*)videoBuffer length:(int)length {
    uint8_t* pBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(length);
    memcpy(pBuffer, videoBuffer, length);
    [[VideoPreviewer instance].dataQueue push:pBuffer length:length];
}
```

My translation was just the below, however, the app crashes.
As it requires a USB connection to a drone in this case, i can't debug it.

```
func camera(camera: DJICamera!, didReceivedVideoData videoBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length: Int32)
{
    VideoPreviewer.instance().dataQueue.push(videoBuffer, length: length)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I compiled and it worked.

```
func camera(camera: DJICamera!, didReceivedVideoData videoBuffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length: Int32) {
        // keep 'buffer' as 'var', 'let' will crash VideoPreviewer
        var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(Int(length))
        memcpy(buffer, videoBuffer, Int(length))
        VideoPreviewer.instance().dataQueue.push(buffer, length: length)
    }
```